# How to track how many times a function was called with a specific parameter

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to set up a jasmine test to not just track how many times a function is called. I would like to track how many times a function is called with a certain parameter.

Here is my current test spec:

```
describe('fizzBuzz', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            // console.log = jasmine.createSpy('log');
            spyOn(console, 'log');
            fizzBuzz();
        })

        it("should test for the fizzBuzz's console output", function () {
        expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('FizzBuzz');
        });
        it('tracks how many times FizzBuzz is called', function(){
            expect(console.log.callCount).toEqual(6);
        });
    })
```

In my second spec, the callCount is equal to how many times console.log is called. I would like to track how many times it was called with the argument 'FizzBuzz'.  Is there a way to chain my first spec with my second? I have tried a lot of variations and can't come to a solution.

Here is the code I would like to test:

```
var fizzBuzz = function(){
    var start = 1;
    while(start <= 100){
        if(start % 3 === 0 && start % 5 === 0){
            console.log('FizzBuzz');
        } else if (start % 3 === 0){
            console.log('Fizz');
        } else if (start % 5 === 0){
            console.log('Buzz');
        } else {
            console.log(start);
        }
        start++;
    }
};
```

I am using the console.log parameters to determine if the code is correct.  Ex: If console.log is called 6 times out of 100 with the parameter FizzBuzz, their code would abide to the guidelines.

UPDATE:

Current Error from Testem:

```
fizzBuzz tracks how many times console.log('FizzBuzz') is called.
    ✘ TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7357/EJSLoops.js:31:43)
        at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost:7357/testem/jasmine.js:1064:17)
        at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:7357/testem/jasmine.js:2096:31)
        at jasmine.Queue.start (http://localhost:7357/testem/jasmine.js:2049:8)
        at jasmine.Spec.execute (http://localhost:7357/testem/jasmine.js:2376:14)
        at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:7357/testem/jasmine.js:2096:31)
        at onComplete (http://localhost:7357/testem/jasmine.js:2092:18)
        at jasmine.Spec.finish (http://localhost:7357/testem/jasmine.js:2350:5)
        at null.onComplete (http://localhost:7357/testem/jasmine.js:2377:10)
        at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:7357/testem/jasmine.js:2106:14)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var fizzBuzz = function(){
    var start = 1;
    while(start <= 100){
        if(start % 3 === 0 && start % 5 === 0){
            console.log('FizzBuzz');
        } else if (start % 3 === 0){
            console.log('Fizz');
        } else if (start % 5 === 0){
            console.log('Buzz');
        } else {
            console.log(start);
        }
        start++;
    }
};

describe('fizzBuzz', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        // console.log = jasmine.createSpy('log');
        spyOn(console, 'log');
        fizzBuzz();
    });

    it("should test for the fizzBuzz's console output", function () {
        expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('FizzBuzz');
    });

    it("tracks how many times console.log('FizzBuzz') is called", function(){

        var callcount = console.log.calls.count();
        var paramcount = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < callcount; i++){
            if(console.log.calls.argsFor(i) == 'FizzBuzz'){
                paramcount++;
            }
        }
        expect(paramcount).toEqual(6);

    });
});
```

Comment: I like this approach, I think this can work. Unfortunately I keep getting an 'undefined' TypeError: undefined is not a function in my test spec. I have been getting this error in other attempts and am not exactly sure what the undefined is referring to.

Comment: The update I just made to my code works for me as is. That is exactly how I have it in my spec.js file so if you're still getting that error there is something else going on. Do you have any other functions running on your spec script?

Comment: I'm not sure. I copied and pasted the code above and tried it in two separate js files.  I keep getting 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' I'm trying to find out what in the code is 'undefined'.

Comment: Do you have jQuery included in either in your spec.js or specRunner.html? `Console.log()` is a jQuery function so if you don't that might be your problem

Comment: I do currently have jquery. It is a dependency for Testem(https://github.com/airportyh/testem) which is what I am using to run my tests.

Comment: It looks like testem should give you the line number of the undefined function, is there anything in the error report that might tell you where to look?

Comment: I updated and added the error in my comments. Looking into those specific lines right now. I really appreciate the time you are taking to help me debug this.